# How to left-align a table in LaTeX

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

There are many Q&A's about left-aligning either table content-cells, or table captions. I'd like to left-align tables (or any/all floats for that matter). I would like to be able to tell that requirement in the preamble.

**EDIT:** My preamble looks like this (I've no idea what is generating this behaviour, so I'll just dump everything here. Generated by pandoc for the most part):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
% This is needed because raggedright in table elements redefines \\:
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\let\PBS=\PreserveBackslash
\usepackage{graphicx}
% We will generate all images so they have a width \maxwidth. This means
% that they will get their normal width if they fit onto the page, but
% are scaled down if they would overflow the margins.
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,unicode=true]{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[font={sf,footnotesize}]{floatrow}
\usepackage{calc}
\floatsetup[table]{style=ruled,
  objectset=raggedleft,
  justification=raggedleft,
  margins=raggedright,
  midcode=captionskip,
  captionskip=10pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[font={small,it},
  justification=justified,
  format=hang,
  labelfont={bf},
  singlelinecheck=false,
  labelsep=quad]{caption}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion]{microtype}
```

Comment: Tables and other floats should be left-aligned by default. If you are not seeing this then probably you are using a nonstandard \documentclass is that is doing something unusual.

Comment: Oh bummer, just ran it through without the wrapper to see how the output looks, and it looks like pandoc inserts `\centering` for every `\begin{<<float>>}`. I guess that makes my question a non-question, really, unless you can somehow counter the `\centering` inside preamble.

Comment: I haven't written a pandoc converter, but if you find out which directory they live in, you could start a new `hg branch`, copy the latex writer, grep for the `\centering` lines and remove those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\let\centering\relax` in the preamble will cancel `\centering` everywhere, or to be more selective and only cancel in floats, you can try

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@float\@float
\def\@float{\let\centering\relax\old@float}
\makeatother
```

You will still need to edit the `\floatsetup{}` line as lockstep described.

Answer (score 6):

The `\floatsetup` command of the floatrow package is the culprit. In your preamble, replace

```
\floatsetup[table]{style=ruled,
  objectset=raggedleft,
  justification=raggedleft,
  margins=raggedright,
  midcode=captionskip,
  captionskip=10pt}
```

with

```
\floatsetup[table]{style=ruled,
  objectset=raggedright,
  margins=raggedright,
  midcode=captionskip,
  captionskip=10pt}
\floatsetup[figure]{%
  objectset=raggedright,
  margins=raggedright,
  midcode=captionskip,
  captionskip=10pt}
```

for starters. Then decide if you really want to adopt different styles for tables and figures (and possible other float types). If not, replace my suggestion with one `\floatsetup` command (without `[table]` or `[figure]`).

EDIT: Just omitting `\floatsetup` will still produce horizontally centered floats - this is the default behaviour of floatrow.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when working with a table in Beamer that I wanted left-justified.

An easy hack I found was to place an `\hfill\` after `\end{tabular}`.  It fills all the way to the space (the `\` after `\hfill`) and hence pushes the table to the left.

Of course this doesn't scale since you need to add `\hfill\` every time.

Comment: This may not scale, but it is the only simple solution that works.

And as a bonus, you don't need to overhaul your tables. Thanks!