# How to left-align a table in LaTeX with nonstandard document class

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, adjustbox

I need to align my table with the left margin of my page. The `adjustbox` package looks to be the solution, but I'm having difficulty implementing it. I realize my question is potentially a duplicate to this one, [How to left-align a table in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9707/how-to-left-align-a-table-in-latex), but I'm still unsure how to execute this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[doc,12pt,floatsintext,longtable,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}  %automatically makes figure/table captions single space.
\usepackage{adjustbox} % Potential solution?
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text only

\geometry{reset, letterpaper, height=9in, width=6in, hmarginratio=1:1, vmarginratio=1:1, marginparsep=0pt, marginparwidth=0pt, headheight=15pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}  
\vspace{0.5in}

\begin{adjustbox}{left=-0.25cm}
\begin{tabular}{ l l } 
AUC & Area under the curve \\
AOU & American Ornithologists' Union \\ 
AR5 & Fifth Assessment Report \\ 
BRT & Boosted regression trees \\
cAUC & Calibrated area under the curve \\ 
CMIP5 & Coupled Model Intercomparison Project Phase 5 \\
GAM & Generalized additive model \\
GBIF & Global Biodiversity Information Facility \\
GCM & General circulation model \\
GIS & Geographic information systems \\
IPCC & International Panel on Climate Change \\ 
MaxEnt & Maximum entropy \\
PRISM & Parameter-Elevation Relationships on Independent Slopes Model \\
RF & Random forest regression trees \\ 
RCP & Representative concentration pathway \\
SDM & Species distribution model \\
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\vspace{0.25in}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As you can see with the `showframe` package, the `tabular` environment isn't fully left-justified as is the text. I would like the `tabular` environment to be positioned like the text.

Comment: You might want to do `\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}` Right now, your tabular is getting indented because you have an empty line in front of it and thus start a new paragraph. Tabulars always do have some spacing on the sides of each column. If you want to get rid of the left side space, `@{}l` is your friend.

Comment: Did you try your code with a standard class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use the facilities of the `adjustbox` package; use `\noindent` instead, and set up the `tabular`'s structure as `\begin{tabular}{@{} l l }`.

I'd say, incidentally, that `apa6` is a reasonably well known document class; I wouldn't call it "nonstandard".

By the way, if you need the material in the table to be single-spaced, I'd encase the `tabular` environment in a `table` environment, as follows:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

If you go this route, the `\noindent` instruction isn't needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[doc,12pt,floatsintext,longtable,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}  %automatically makes figure/table captions single space.
\usepackage{adjustbox} % Potential solution?
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text only

\geometry{reset, letterpaper, height=9in, width=6in, hmarginratio=1:1, vmarginratio=1:1, marginparsep=0pt, marginparwidth=0pt, headheight=15pt, showframe}
\shorttitle{}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}  
\vspace{0.5in}

\noindent   % <----
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l } % <----
AUC & Area under the curve \\
AOU & American Ornithologists' Union \\ 
AR5 & Fifth Assessment Report \\ 
BRT & Boosted regression trees \\
cAUC & Calibrated area under the curve \\ 
CMIP5 & Coupled Model Intercomparison Project Phase 5 \\
GAM & Generalized additive model \\
GBIF & Global Biodiversity Information Facility \\
GCM & General circulation model \\
GIS & Geographic information systems \\
IPCC & International Panel on Climate Change \\ 
MaxEnt & Maximum entropy \\
PRISM & Parameter-Elevation Relationships on Independent Slopes Model \\
RF & Random forest regression trees \\ 
RCP & Representative concentration pathway \\
SDM & Species distribution model \\
\end{tabular}


\vspace{0.25in}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Appreciate the advice. I need double spacing for the items and `\noindent` & `@{}` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}  



\begin{tabular}{ l l } \\
AUC & Area under the curve \\
AOU & American Ornithologists' Union \\ 
AR5 & Fifth Assessment Report \\ 
BRT & Boosted regression trees \\
cAUC & Calibrated area under the curve \\ 
CMIP5 & Coupled Model Intercomparison Project Phase 5 \\
GAM & Generalized additive model \\
GBIF & Global Biodiversity Information Facility \\
GCM & General circulation model \\
GIS & Geographic information systems \\
IPCC & International Panel on Climate Change \\ 
MaxEnt & Maximum entropy \\
PRISM & Parameter-Elevation Relationships on Independent Slopes Model \\
RF & Random forest regression trees \\ 
RCP & Representative concentration pathway \\
SDM & Species distribution model \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I did not understand your difficulty. But I removed all packages and compiled it.  It comes in the page form.

Comment: In your answer, you also changed from the `apa6` documentclass to `article`. With `article` you don't get the mentioned indentation since the first paragraph after a `\section` header is not indented as opposed to all following sections. Since there is no text between section header and tabular, the tabular is treated like the first paragraph. Hence no indentation with the `article` class. `apa6` on the other hand seems to indent the first line of all paragraphs. Therefore the `tabular` is indented as well.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).